# Telegram start new chat with Python

Tags: python, telegram

I want to start a new chat in Telegram with a Python script but I know with neither Telegram's BOT nor its API it is possibile.
**I don't want the user starts the chat with a BOT before!**

However I was wandering if you can achieve this in anther way. I mean, when you create a new chat with Telegram application, there will be, somehow, and endpoint which handle this request.
Why is it impossibile to create a Python script which emulates this action?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't want the user starts the chat with a BOT before!

This is **not** possible. A Bot can **never** start a chat, that has to be done by the user him/her self.

After the user has started a conversation with the Bot, you can send anything to the user until the user stops the conversation.

Comment: Yes I know it is not possible. I wrote "I don't want the user starts the chat with a BOT before" indeed!

I want a way to avoid user writes to a BOT first. How does Telegram application let the user starts a new chat? I suppose it calls some endpoints